# Display two divs on same line without blankspace in between, inside a div with contenteditable="true"

Tags: css, html, contenteditable

```
<div id="test" class="pad" contenteditable="true">
  <div id="a" class="fif">text1</div>
  <div id="b" class="fif">text2</div>
</div>
```

As in above code I have a `contenteditable` div and many divs inside it (child divs). Number of child divs vary dynamically and also the content between div tags. I want `text1` and `text2` (i.e. content between div tags) to be displayed on same line, without any blank space in between. Also while typing in `contenteditable` div if I press ENTER key it should go to next line.

I tried `float:left` but it does not allow me to go to the next line when I press ENTER key while typing in `contenteditable` div. `display:inline`, `span` when used show blank space in between 2 div contents. I tried using `flex` from http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/ but didn't get desired output.

Comment: Starting point fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UwZsm/

Comment: Thanks for answer but, still there remains a blank space between 2 divs of class="fif", which I do not want.

Answer (score 14):

Just make the `<div>`s have `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` and remove the white space between them in the HTML source.

Whether you use `inline` or `inline-block` depends on how you want content within the divs to be laid out. Here's [an MDN article on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Visual_formatting_model).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/GVZPX/

CSS:

```
.fif {
    display: inline; /* Or inline-block */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test" class="pad" contenteditable="true">
  <div id="a" class="fif">text1</div><div id="b" class="fif">text2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">1</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `display:inline` for the inner div

```
 #test div{
      display:inline;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well

```
.pad {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow:hidden  /*  first */
}
.fif {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    float:left  /* second part */
}
```

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/UwZsm/2/)

Comment: Thanks to isherwood for the initial jsFiddle

Comment: The new line problem still exist

Comment: The one he mentioned. When you are for example o text 1 and you press enter, it does not go to new line

Comment: @MIIB **"Also while typing in contenteditable div if I press ENTER key it should go to next line"**  so is it SUPPOSED to go to next line ?

Comment: Correct. It should go to next line. That's why it is dificult

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question more than 5 years after it was originally posted, since none of the answers barring Tim Down's strike at the actual problem. Elaborating it further, here is what happens when you inline-block two elements:

The white space between the two inline block divs is expected. When you inline an element (or inline-block in this case), you are in affect instructing the browser to put all the elements on the same line side by side. By doing so, you are in affect treating your divs equivalent to the white-spaces on the line (space/tab etc) as they share the line space.

In your snippet, you have 4 space characters between the closing div tag  (`</div>`) and the next opening `<div>` tag. Browser rendering engine shrinks multiple spaces into a single space and that single space takes up the extra character which is what you are observing in this case.

So, once you understand the above, you can easily solve this by adopting one of the many workarounds like:

```
<div id="a" class="fif">text1</div><!-- 
--><div id="b" class="fif">text2</div>
```

or

```
<div id="a" class="fif">text1</div
><div id="b" class="fif">text2</div>
```

or

```
<div id="a" class="fif">text1</
div><div id="b" class="fif">text2</
div>
```

The last one is a invalid XML, but browsers do not barf at this.

Your fiddle is forked with the above workarounds here: http://jsfiddle.net/AshwinPrabhuB/otavbncr/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but this might help: http://jsfiddle.net/UwZsm/3

```
.fif {display: inline-block; margin: 0 -4px 0 0;}
```

Comment: I intend to have something that appears like this [http://jsfiddle.net/hari_OM/4GfcJ/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_OM/4GfcJ/2/) .  But it is not exactly what I want since even though no blank space is seen between 2 child divs of class="fif", blank space exists and can be noticed by user while  he does **backspace** i.e. he would have to also erase an extra blankspace in between 2 divs.

Answer (score 0):

I tested out an idea, and it worked for what you are talking about I believe.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            .fif{
                padding:0px;
                float:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" class="pad" contenteditable="true">
          <div id="a" class="fif">text1</div>
          <div id="b" class="fif">text2</div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks 4 answer but it isn't what I want. I intend to have something that appears like this [http://jsfiddle.net/hari_OM/4GfcJ/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_OM/4GfcJ/2/) . But it is not exactly what I want since even though no blank space is seen between 2 child divs of class="fif", blank space exists and can be noticed by user while he does backspace i.e. he would have to also erase an extra blankspace in between 2 divs

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figure it out if you have access to the html code.

```
    <div id="test" class="pad" contenteditable="true">
        <table>
          <tr>
           <td>
            <div id="a" class="fif">text1</div>
           </td>
           <td>
            <div id="b" class="fif">text2</div>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
    </div>



<style>
.pad {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow:hidden
}
.fif {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table,td,tr{
padding:0;
}

#a {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#b {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but blank space is still visible.End user should feel as if "text1" and "text2" belong to same sentence even though they might belong to 2 different divs. Also while typing the end user should feel as if he is editing a single continuous sentence and not 2 distinct ones.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hari_OM/4GfcJ/2/

Here it is without any space.

```
<div id="test" class="pad" contenteditable="true">
    <div id="a" class="fif">text1</div><div id="b" class="fif">text2</div>
</div>
```