# Divs in the same line not displayed in css

Tags: html, css

I have two divs (.diva and .divb) inside another div container (#divs-test).

```
<div id="divs-test">
    <div class="diva"></div>
    <div class="divb"></div>
</div>
```

I want to show both divs in the same line, so this is the css I use:

```
#divs-test{
    width: 100%;
}

#divs-test > div{
    height:40%;
}

.diva{
    width: 70%; 
}
.divb{
    width: 30%;
}
```

But the divs are not displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the jfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/cspX5/

Comment: They needs heights.. or at least contents within them if you want them to be visible.

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166673/display-two-divs-on-same-line-without-blankspace-in-between-inside-a-div-with-c

Comment: First off, your sample code should be a minimal example of your problem, your fiddle obviously isn't. Secondly, use inline-block displaying.

Comment: divs are block elements. either add the display:inline or display:inline-block to them, or use spans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make a percentage height like `height:40%` work, you must do one of these:

- Set a `height` property to the parent, different than `auto`
- Remove the element from the normal flow of the document (e.g. `position: absolute`), so that its height won't affect parent's one.

If not, the height of the children, which is set relatively to the parent's one, would depend on itself, since parent's height would depend on its content's height.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that "Remove the element from the normal flow ..."? Why do you think it is required for percents to work?

Comment: @c-smile Because the height of an element with `height:auto` depends on its contents. But if you set the height of the contents relatively to parent's height, it's a circular definition. To break it, either the parent shouldn't have `height:auto`, or the child shouldn't affect parent's height (you can do that removing it from the normal flow)

Comment: In order percentage to work you need parent with known height at the time when CSS processor need to get its computed value. For `position:absolute` computed value determination can be delayed until all static content gets replaced and so positioned elements can use parent with `height:auto` for resolving percentage against its static auto height. But this has nothing with "... won't affect ..." strictly speaking.

Comment: @c-smile Well, it's how I understand and remember it, and kinda works. If you can remember precisely the algorithms described in the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-box/#Calculating), good for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Divs are displayed, they just have zero height, if you will add

```
div { border:1px solid }
```

you will see them, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/cspX5/3/

In general: height in percents (of parent height) works only if parent of the element has defined non auto height.